# Trouble passing array of JSON objects to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, stringify

The following loops through several rows of a table collecting data as it goes.
For each iteration I say $jrow = JSON.stringify ($rowdata) and then $jschedule.push ($jrow);

After the stringify, a row looks like this...
{"count":1,"bmaclass":"18-007","customer":"CST4070","course":"CRS0001","evdate":"","time":"","location":"0","stu1":"STU2336","stu2":"STU2623","stu3":"STU6808","instructor":"0","evaluator":"0"}

I would expect this to yield an array of strings which I then stringify and pass to PHP; however PHP sees nothing.  I am at a loss as to how I can create this array and pass it to PHP.  Seems like I've done it before but I'm having no luck this time.

```
var $jschedule = [];
$("table.tngdays tr").each (function ($index, $row){
            $this = $(this);
            $this.css("background","orange");

            $time = $this.find('input.time');
            $evtime = $time.val();
            $time.css("background","pink");

            $evdate = $this.find ("input.date").val(),
            $evtime = $this.find ("input.time").val(),
            $bmaclass = $("select.pendingClasses").val()
            $location = $this.find (".loc").val()
            $instructor = $this.find (".ins").val()
            $evaluator = $this.find (".tce").val()

            //console.log ($evdate, $evtime);

            $rowdata = {
               count      : $count,
               bmaclass   : $bmaclass,
               customer   : $result.customer,
               course     : $result.course,
               evdate     : $evdate,
               time       : $evtime,
               location   : $location,
               stu1       : $result.p1,
               stu2       : $result.p2,
               stu3       : $result.p3,
               instructor : $instructor,
               evaluator  : $evaluator
            }
            $count ++;

            $jrow = JSON.stringify($rowdata);

            console.log ("Rowdata = " + typeof($jrow))
            console.log ($jrow);
            $jschedule.push ($jrow);

            })


        }) //each


        $data = {
           events:$jschedule
        }

        $data = JSON.stringify($data);
        console.log ($data);

        $.post ("/Training/ScheduleClass/pdo_saveClassEvents.php",{data:$data}, function ($result){
           console.log ("Events = " + $result);
        })
```

Thanks,
DMD

Comment: Thanks,

Yes, both were typos.  I typed that line in after pasting the rest of the code.  I have fixed my errors

Comment: `console.log($data)` before the $.post and see what it has, or check your developer tools network requests for the request and see what is being sent.

Comment: You are double encoding. Call JSON.stringify only once. Also try without calling stringify. If memory serves, jQuery handles that automatically.

Comment: If I don't stringify the data, DEV Tools shows an array of strings.>[ ]

If I do stringify it shows an empty array [ ]

Comment: Found the problem.  There were a misplaced set of closing tags }).  When I moved things inside the proper tags, all was well.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a misplaced set of closing tags.  Once I moved the post inside the proper tags, the problem disappeared.

Thanks all